# Angular Js and testing directives with own scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, karma-runner

In my project i have directive

```
 .directive('addComment', function () {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                collection: '='
            },
            templateUrl: "addComment.html",
            controller: function($scope) {
                $scope.newComment = $scope.newComment  || {};
            }
        };
    })
```

with template   `<div>{{newComment.text}}</div>`

and test

```
addComment = compile('<div data-add-comment="" data-collection="comments"></div>')(scope);
addComment.scope().newComment = { text: 'new comment' };
scope.$apply();
//Functionality to assert
```

But now i have issue if i want to set new value  `addComment.scope().newComment` then scope is null after i used apply function. So i need to compile addComment again.

Is this here any better way to do that?

Comment: you can use `.isolateScope()` instead of `.scope()` to get the reference of directive's isolated scope

Comment: maybe this can help : http://blog.revolunet.com/blog/2013/12/05/unit-testing-angularjs-directive/